# Insert into SQL table and retrieve object

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to insert a name into a name table (`tName`), database properties in my `Name` class and I created a model `Add` method to add the value into database.

I then want to return the `na` object with the last added parameter.

How can I do this?

```
public Name Add(string name)
{
    Name na = new Name();
    using (DatabaseCommand cmd = 
                     new DatabaseCommand("INSERT INTO tName (NA) values (@nm)"))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm", name);
        int created=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (created == 1)
        {

        }
        return na;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to return back afterwards, can you edit your post and explain more what you are trying to get back?

Comment: Which SQL server and version are you using?  The answer is different for each SQL server (MySQL vs MS SQL vs PostgreSQL etc.).  What fields are in the table that need to be populated back to the `Name` object instance?

Comment: Sql servr 2008 and i wnt to return ID and name

Comment: scott Chamberlain: i want return last added name and id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you familiar with the optional `OUTPUT` clause of an `INSERT` statement?  You can execute a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO tName (NA)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, INSERTED.tName
VALUES (@nm)
```

This allows you to output the newly-created ID of the inserted row.  Read more about `OUTPUT` clauses [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Of course if you do it like this from C#, you will have to use `ExecuteReader` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`, since we are now interested in the return value of the query, not just the number of rows affected.  Read more about `ExecuteReader` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335691.aspx).